# Push Batch Payment's payment reference number to Custom Export Scenario

Tags: c#, acumatica

I am trying to get the reference number of each payment listed within a batch to the code behind of the Export scenario provider.

[image]

The hard coded values pull through perfectly to the method behind, but the payment refnbr gives a null value

[image]

Is anyone able to shed some light on this? It seems to be something simple, but all the iterations I have tried did not work. I compared to the ACH provider also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the CABatchEntry BLC there are 2 data views: BatchPayments and APPaymentList - both to show payments listed within a batch:

```
public class CABatchEntry : PXGraph<CABatchEntry>
{
    ...

    public PXSelectJoin<CABatchDetail,
        LeftJoin<APPayment,
            On<CABatchDetail.origDocType, Equal<APPayment.docType>,
            And<CABatchDetail.origRefNbr, Equal<APPayment.refNbr>>>>,
        Where<CABatchDetail.batchNbr, Equal<Current<CABatch.batchNbr>>>> BatchPayments;

    public PXSelectJoin<APPayment,
        InnerJoin<CABatchDetail,
            On<CABatchDetail.origModule, Equal<GL.BatchModule.moduleAP>,
            And<CABatchDetail.origDocType, Equal<APPayment.docType>,
            And<CABatchDetail.origRefNbr, Equal<APPayment.refNbr>>>>>,
        Where<CABatchDetail.batchNbr, Equal<Current<CABatch.batchNbr>>>> APPaymentList;

    ...
}
```

Within integration scenario you are only allowed to use fields of the main data view DAC, which is **CABatchDetail** for `BatchPayments` and **APPayment** for `APPaymentList`. Since ***Reference Nbr.*** column is bound to the **APPayment.RefNbr** field, you must use `APPaymentList` data view both as **Source Object** and inside the formula:
[image]

Comment: This poses a problem with duplicates. I have mappings to export the Vendor (Payments | Vendor) also for example. So the scenario picks up each Payment item in the Batch, then within each one it calls the PaymentList which contains multiple items which it then creates; then it goes to the next Payment in the Batch, and again calls the full PaymentList, etc. So instead of getting 2 records exported, it exports 2 x 2

Comment: It seems to have worked. I see that the use of the Payments Source Object does not work together with the APPaymentList Source Object. When only using APPaymentList it works fine and creates the file as intended. Thank you for the assistance.